# I can't seem to get mod_proxy_html working at all - no debug output, no errors

Tags: html, apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm running apache 2.0.52, and I've compiled the mod_proxy_html module (version 3.1), apache starts fine, no errors. The only problem is that the module appears to do nothing - I'm not even getting any debugging output in the error log, so I'm a little stumped, as I fdon't even have any logging to point at a clue why it isn't working. The proxying itself works fine, but there's no url modification going on.

Here's the snippet from my httpd.conf file:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
LogLevel Debug

ProxyPass /forms http://internal:7777/forms
ProxyPass /reports http://internal:7777/reports
ProxyPassReverse /forms http://internal:7777/forms
ProxyPassReverse /reports http://internal:7777/reports

ProxyHTMLURLMap http://internal:7777/reports /reports
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've still not located why it isn't logging, but the missing magic incantation was

SetOutputFilter proxy-html

which I suspect sets mod_filter to pass all outgoing content via mod_proxy_html

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer.

```
ProxyHTMLCharsetOut *
```

> The special token ProxyHTMLCharsetOut * will generate output using the
>   same encoding as the input.

To compare with `SetOutputFilter proxy-html`, search it on the following page, and read the discussion.

Ref. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmlcharsetout